# How can i return the keys of a specific value in Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I have the following entries in my HashMap

```
<key1,value1>
<key2,value2>
<key3,value2>
<key4,value4>
<key5,value2>
```

I would like to find all the Keys that contain the value "value2".
The answer would be a KeySet containing the following keys:
{key2,key3,key4}

Is it possible to accomplish that in a HashMap?
thanks

Comment: I am guessing that you are ruling out iterating over the HashMap and checking the value corresponding to each key..

Comment: You are looking for a bidirectional map, aka "multimap". There is an implementation in the [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).  It's also not hard to do this yourself... the reverse map uses the value as the key (assuming the value class has `hashCode()` and `equals()`) and a `List<Key>` as the value.  `List<Key>` is required because you'll have more than one key mapping to a given value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just Iterate entries of your map and check if the value of the current entry is equal to "value2" then add it to Set.
try this

```
Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    if(entry.getValue().equals("value2")
    {
      keySet.add(entry.getKey());
    }

}
```

I guess there is no other option since you have duplicate values in your map.

Answer (score 1):

Map is supposed to use in such way that access  the values using the keys, but it seems you are doing it in reverse.

If you are sure about what you are doing, there is no good way to accomplish. Iterate over map and store the keys in separate list.

More over Look at Gauva's [Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Multimaps), that might suits for your requirment.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to find all the Keys that contain the value "value2". The answer would be a KeySet containing the following keys: {key2,key3,key4}

Two options:

- new map where the values are the keys and the keys are the values (if every key and value are unique)
- iterate through the entries of your map and check if the value of the current entry is equal to "value2", if yes add it a set with the results

Comment: The first option you propose has a problem, unless the HashMap can support multiple values for a key, only the latest key-value pair would find place in the new hash map as the other ones would be overwritten

Comment: I guess there is no other way to achieve except the ones you have listed, or is there? The existing solutions seem to have a very high complexity.